# Proxy URL 'incache....com:8080' does not contain a valid hostname

Tags: version-control, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Recently I was forced to switch from SVN to TFS.
I'm trying to get this working with TEE on our RedHat box.

Any action seems to end with something like this:

```
user@rh: tf -map $/XX/XX . -workspace:app-job -server:http://tfs.domain.com:8080/tfs/TFS2008/ -profile:TFS1_PRF_C
Password:
An error occurred: Proxy URL 'incache.domain.com:8080' does not contain a valid hostname.
```

Could someone help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague about what you expect to happen here (are you supposed to be using an HTTP proxy to access your TFS server?  Or is the problem that it's assuming your HTTP proxy?)

I'm going to assume that you *do not* need to use an HTTP proxy to access your internal TFS server, since in most corporate environments your proxy is used to get outside the network, not inside.  By default, the Team Explorer Everywhere CLC does try to use your system HTTP proxy, however this is configurable in your connection profile.

In order to override your default system HTTP proxy for that profile, you can set the profile property `httpProxyIgnoreGlobal` to `true`:

```
tf profile -edit -boolean:httpProxyIgnoreGlobal=true TFS1_PRF_C
```